# How to include .dll references in dotnetcore output?

Tags: .net, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have created a c# library using .net core.
When the project is built, only the primary dll is included in the "debug" (etc...) output directory.

This makes sense if you're distributing the library via nuget, but my target for distribution is AWS Lambda. For that, I need to upload all of my library's dependencies in a single zip package.

I'm looking at dotnet-pack and dotnet-publish, but can't seem to figure out a way to tell dotnet to build my project, and move all of the referenced DLLs into the output directory.

I've searched all over and have found a lot of information about the location of dependencies and how to pack for nuget, but I cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish what I need.

I am not new to .net, but am pretty new to core. The project type is an 'xproj' if that helps.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [self-contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd)